# Can't run Spyder or .py(w) scripts with Windows 10

Tags: python-2.7, windows-10, spyder

Can't open Spyder2 in Windows 10.0 (# 10240): the icon just appears briefly. Python 2.7.10 and Spyder 2.3.1 were loaded with Anaconda 2.3.0 (64-bit). The python console works fine - but I can't get my *.py or *.pyw files running. There is probably some message in the Python console when attemtping to open Spyder, but I don't know how to capture it.

Answer (score 1):

First, one correction: the problem was with starting Spyder, not running .py or .pyw files. Anyway, things work all right now after de-installing Spyder and Python, and reinstalling the Python(x,y) package (instead of Anaconda's). Then, when starting Spyder from the Python(x,y)start window, it behaves normally.